# How to Fix: "Must be an array type but is resolved to a string"

Tags: java

Creating a program that uses a menu to call separate modules of a simple health tracker for a beginner programming course.
Would appreciate some help concerning the exact reason why the array isn't working properly and is "resolved to a string"
I have a lot more to add before i can submit the program but this is holding me up.

It is in `Module 3`, the line attempting to recall the array

I'm leaving the entire code so far here because I don't understand what I've done wrong and am hoping this place is more helpful than the useless forums at uni.

```
public class HealthMate {


    double bmi, bmr, heightM, weightKG;
    int age, week = 7, days = 1;
    int calories[] = new int[days];
    int menuChoiceInt;
    char genderChar;
    boolean male;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HealthMate firstObj = new HealthMate(); 
        firstObj.menu();
    }

    public void menu() {
        while (menuChoiceInt != 4) {

            String menu = "HealthMate Alpha 0.1 \n " + "Please make a numerical selection \n";
            menu += "[1] Enter or Update your Details\n";
            menu += "[2] Return BMI and BMR \n"; // menu options call different modules
            menu += "[3] Weekly Tracker and Advice \n";
            menu += "[4] Exit \n";
            String menuChoiceString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menu);
            menuChoiceInt = Integer.parseInt(menuChoiceString);//

            if (menuChoiceString != null) {

                if (menuChoiceInt == 1) {

                    genderChar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter your Gender as either M or F").charAt(0);

                    heightM = Double.parseDouble(
                            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Height in Meters,\n eg 1.73 for 173 cm.: "));
                    if (heightM <= 0) {
                        heightM = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Error! Enter a postitive number"));
                    }
                    weightKG = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Weight in Kilograms"));
                    if (weightKG <= 0) {
                        weightKG = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Error! Enter a postitive number"));
                    }
                    bmi = weightKG / Math.pow(heightM, 2.0);
                    male = genderChar == 'M';
                    if (male) {
                        bmr = (10 * weightKG) + (62.5 * heightM) - (5 * age) + 5; 

                    } else {
                        bmr = (10 * weightKG) + (62.5 * heightM) - (5 * age) - 161; 
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Specific BMI and BMR have been ");
                        menuChoiceInt = Integer.parseInt(menuChoiceString);// recall menu
                    }
                }

                if (menuChoiceInt == 2) if (bmi < 18.5) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", You are underweight.\n" + "Your BMR is " + bmr);
                } else if (bmi < 25) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your BMI is " + bmi
                            + ", You are within the healthy weight range.\n" + "Your BMR is " + bmr);
                } else if (bmi < 30) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Your bmi is " + bmi + ", You are overweight\n" + "Your BMR is " + bmr);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Your bmi is " + bmi + ", You are Obese" + "Your BMR is " + bmr);

                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "This module is supposed to recall your BMI and BMR \n"
                                + "and give general advice on health.");
                {                   
                    menuChoiceInt = Integer.parseInt(menuChoiceString);
                }
                if (menuChoiceInt == 3) {
                    while (days > week) {
                    calories[week] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Calories for day"[days]);// employee salary
                    days = days + 1;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "This module is supposed to store data in an array over the course \n"
                                    + "of a week to show you your pattern of intake vs output.");
                    }
                    {   
                        menuChoiceInt = Integer.parseInt(menuChoiceString);
                    }
                } else if (menuChoiceInt == 4) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the calorie input to be saved over the course of 7 days so I can average it out, compare it to `BMR` and `Activity` level and give general advice on whether you are in surplus or deficit of calorie intake.

PS: Maybe if you have years of experience don't start your reply with "Well its obvious that..." and continue your mockery of someone who started programming less than a month ago as you people so often seem to on this website.

Comment: Im aware some of the message text isnt finished. I've been extremely sick while trying to finish this thing and I dont want to be shredded for being new.

Comment: `"Enter Calories for day"[days]` is not valid in Java. Use `"Enter Calories for day".charAt(days)`. Or is it a typo?

Comment: Honestly the fastest way to figure out where the problem is (and what I would in fact do, if I were sitting with you as a TA in your course), would be to run the code in _debug_ mode, and step through each line by line, until we hit the problem.  Most likely, it would be obvious what is causing the error.

Comment: Please can you post error logs.

Comment: From what I can so far you've been informed of how to solve the current issue however, your next problem is going to be the **calories[]** integer Array. You have declared and initialized this array to 1 meaning it can hold only a single element (unless I'm missing something here). Arrays can't grow to hold more elements without the use of some thumper code. Might be a good Idea to utilize an ArrayList<Integer> object instead since it can grow as needed.

Comment: We arent allowed to use Array Lists for this assignment otherwise I would have. I fell ill during the week on Array's so catching up has been hard. I believe it is supposed to be 7, or "week"

Answer (score 1):

You have `int days = 1`, but you use it as `[day]` - this is incorrect in `java`:

```
calories[week] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Calories for day " + days));
```